# GitHub Pages: custom CNAME on a Directory

Tags: subdomain, github-pages, cname

Is it possible to set a CNAME to a directory of a github-pages site? For example:

Without CNAME `username.github.io/blog/index.html`

And with CNAME `blog.mydomain.com/index.html`

I didn't find anything on the help page, so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a `CNAME` in the blog folder of `username.github.io` repository.

But you can set a `CNAME` (blog.mydomain.com) at the root of a  `username.github.io/blog` repository.